# How to visualize XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, viewer

I have a task to write down a simple viewer that would show how a .xaml file visually looks like(just like the VS editor, but without editing capabilities). Could you give me any references that would help me?

Comment: Does this help? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/a53ff197-8703-4c6c-8726-45570304fb7b/

Answer (score 3):

you can use [XamlReader.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590398.aspx) method

If you want only viewer, not a designer you can call `XamlReader.Load` method, and assign the result to `ContentControl.Content`

```
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(strXaml);
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
myContentControl.Content = (Button)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
```

**EDIT**
This code loads window from xaml and show it

```
string strXaml = "<Window xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml\" Title=\"MainWindow\" Height=\"350\" Width=\"525\">" +
        "<Grid> <Button Content=\"Button123\" Height=\"23\" HorizontalAlignment=\"Left\" Margin=\"174,41,0,0\" Name=\"button1\" VerticalAlignment=\"Top\" Width=\"75\" />"+
        "</Grid></Window>";

StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(strXaml);

XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
Window obj = (Window)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);

obj.Show();
```

If you are sure that the root element is allways Window, you can skip it. Something like this works for me

```
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(strXaml);
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(stringReader).Document.Descendants().First().DescendantNodes().First();

XmlReader xmlReader = xDoc.CreateReader();
uc.Content = XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
```

Would be better to check if Window exists or not before skipping it

Comment: Did you try this piece of code? I get "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."

Comment: that's because your xaml is invalid, yes it works...please make sure that your xaml have only one root.

Comment: Standart wpf app's mainwindow.xaml file. last line is "this.content = ..."

Comment: ahh, you can't assign Window as a content to ContentControl. You can pass Window, and assign Grid instead of Window

Answer (score 2):

You should start by looking at the [`XamlServices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd294592.aspx) class and its [`Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xaml.xamlservices.parse.aspx) method.